# Excel download stops by moving to another route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Using maatwebsite-excel library, I am exporting data as an Excel file in Laravel application. If the amount of data is large, the export process takes a few seconds to complete. In the mean time, if I click on any other menu tab and move to a new route (any other page within the application), the download process stops. 
I wonder if I am doing something wrong or this is how it is. I see some websites with download functionality (Not necessarily Excel/CSV) but they keep downloading when I move to other pages. 
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Excel::create('Groups', function ($excel) use ($group_set_data) {
        foreach ($group_set_data as $group_set) {
            $counter = 2;
            $excel->sheet($group_set['name'], function ($sheet) use ($group_set, $counter) {
                $sheet->row(1, [
                    'Student',
                    'ID',
                    'grade',
                    'Group Name',
                ]);

                foreach ($group_set['groups'] as $key => $value) {
                    $users = Group::get_users_by_group_id($value['id']);
                    foreach ($users as $user) {
                        $sheet->row($counter, [
                            $user['name'],
                            $user['id'],
                            $user['grade'],
                            $value['name'],
                        ]);
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })->export('xls');
```

Comment: That is correct if you leave the page  once you have initiated the creation of your excel the process will stop. I would say if your rendering takes longer than few seconds to show some sort of a (Loading...) message to indicate to user that they need to wait.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification IamCavic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember that the function 'excel::create..... your code here ...' in a function inside to controller, so you need show finaly route when finish you fuction

this my code:

```
    $msj = "Upload succesfull"; $class = "alert alert-success";

/* ============================  END  ============================ */ 
})->export('xls'); // end read excel::function

return back()->with([]);
```

}

I hope it's help you